# Plone Multi Path Form Solution

Tags: forms, plone, ploneformgen

We've been asked to create a form that is more of a long-form questionnaire, eventually bringing people to the information they need.

Our institution uses Plone and would like to find an existing solution, ideally integrated with Plone.

Is there a Plone plugin that can accomplish this or should we look elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [PlonFormGen](http://plone.org/products/ploneformgen) and its [documentation](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/ploneformgen/)? It allows all kind of adjustments, so might fit your use case.

Answer (score 2):

If it's multi-page surveys you're after, [PloneSurvey](http://plone.org/products/plonesurvey) might fit the bill.

If it's a glorified navigational instrument, you might want to rethink and offer [eea.facetednavigation](http://plone.org/products/eea.facetednavigation)‎ instead